# Making a hole on a not flat surface

Tags: modifiers, project

I am a beginner but I am having some difficulties trying to recreate the holes and elevations pointed out in the picture. First I thought I could achieve that with a cylinder and a boolean modifier, but I am not so sure now.

I am wondering if I could create a circle and "project" it on the surface in any way, as if it was a sticker or a shadow, from which I could extrude. That would be very useful for other projects, so I would like to know if that option exists in Blender. The shrinkwrap modifier isn't making that work, as I first expected.

How would you guys approach this problem?

[[image: Real model]

[image: Blender screenshot]

Attempt with cube + cylinder

[image: 1st attempt]

---

This is my model so far. Any insight on how to get rid of Ngons? [image: Model so far]

Answer (score 4):

You could make sure that you have a 2x2 square topology, create a 8 vertex cylinder, keep it selected and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> > *Intersect (Boolean)*:

[image]

Choose *Difference* and *Fast* in the *Operator* box:

[image]

Join the vertices to have this topology:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, moonboots! I have looptools and have used it before. The problem I see here is that my surface is composed of two planes, one of them being inclined. That method woul be a bit tricky for this situation, I think. O maybe there is an easy way to adapt that to my problem that I cannot see.

Comment: I've edited, does it answer?

Comment: Hi! Yes, it did, but I have some questions: I used that option (I though I could use booleans only through modifiers, thank you!), and I automatically got the hole, instead of the circle shape. No need for extrusion. Is that normal? Also, should I have asubdivided square under the circle shape, as you? I guess it's convenient so I don't get Ngons, but still, it's a bit tricky for me to create those subdivisions shared by two planes. I'll add a screenshot of the result.

Comment: I see the result you show: Use a 8 vertex cylinder instead, and create some orthogonal edge loops in order to have a 2x2 square like in my pictures

Comment: Ok. I have been trying for a while, but I am having problems with making the correct subdivisions on these planes. First I combined the cylinder with a subdivided 2x2x2 cube in order to use the boolean with both and get the exact shape, but I guess the point is not having Ngons around the 2x2 shape either. I will think about it a give it a try later, but if you have some advice, I would appreciate it. I'm still a beginner and get confused with apparently easy things. :S Thank you! I will edit my post with a screenshot of the full model and the result with the 2x2x2 cube.